# deploy a node.js application to api.cloudfoundry.com. and got an error

Tags: cloud-foundry

Error 402: App packaging failed: 'Failed synchronizing resource pool'

I got this error when deploy a node.js application to api.cloudfoundry.com.
the vmc I used is:
vmc 0.3.10

I want to know how does this error happened. Is there something wrong with my vmc? or something wrong with my node.js application?

Thank you.

Comment: First step, get the latest version of vmc, vmc-0.3.18, "gem install vmc".

Comment: Have you had success deploying using the instructions at: http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/frameworks/nodejs/nodejs.html  ?

Comment: Is it possible for you to give a link to the source code of the app so we can try to reproduce the error?

Comment: @eightyoctane thanks for your help. It seems that there is something wrong with my node.js application.

Comment: @Glenn Oppegard thanks for your help. It seems that there is something wrong with my node.js application.

Answer (score 1):

You'll definitely want to upgrade to the latest vmc. "gem update" should refresh it to 0.3.18 for you but if not, "gem install vmc" to grab the newest.

What steps did you follow to deploy the app - did you just run vmc push and follow the prompts, did you have a manifest.yml file in place (probably not as vmc 0.3.10 may have pre-dated manifest support), did you provide additional parameters to vmc push?

Comment: Additional parameter to vmc push such as --runtime=node06 would enforce your app to use node 06 rather than node 04 which is the default for node apps being deployed on cf.com

Comment: I just run 'vmc push' in app's dir, and no other additional parameters.
Thank you for your help. I will try to add this additional parameter.